# Call UISplitViewController from another UIViewController in a UITabBarController app

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm creating an universal App and have a `UITabBarController` for my app's Views. The first tab is a `UISplitViewController` created programatically and the others are `UIViewControllers` designed in IB. How can I call the `UISplitViewController` (my first TabBar) and pass a parameter from another TabBar's `UIViewController` (for example, by tapping a button)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
[((MyViewControllerType*)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]) callMyMethodWithObject:object]
```

Comment: You were right! Once I got the root view controller I set the details view using a viewController variable that points and updates de detail view controller (rootVC.detailsController.detailItem = ...). Thanks!